# Spring @Conditional: Error Message

Tags: java, spring, error-handling

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public Foobar foobar(@Value("${my.value}") String v) {
        return new Foobar(v);
    }

}

@Component
public class MyComp {

    private final Foobar foobar;

    public MyComp(Foobar foobar) {
        this.foobar = foobar;
        System.out.println(foobar);
    }

}
```

If *my.value* is not set, I will get this error message

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'my.value' in string value "${my.value}"
```

Now *my.value* is also secured by @ConditionalOnProperty("my.value")

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @ConditionalOnProperty("my.value")
    @Bean
    public Foobar foobar(@Value("${my.value}") String v) {
        return new Foobar(v);
    }

}
```

If *my.value* is not set, I will get this error message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myComp' defined in file [/home/stephan/workspaces/workspace_mercateo/demo/target/classes/com/example/MyComp.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.Foobar] found for dependency [com.example.Foobar]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.Foobar] found for dependency [com.example.Foobar]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
[...]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.Foobar] found for dependency [com.example.Foobar]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Though spring recognizes that *my.value* is missing there is nothing about this in the output log.

Is there a way to configure spring so that
1) @Conditional is used
and
2) error message contains "*my.value* is missing"
?

Comment: Which is the 'myComp' bean, can you add it to the question? My guess is that you use the conditional on property for the foobar bean, but you also try to auto wire it in 'myComp' bean.

Comment: I added MyComp. I do not Autowire Foobar in MyComp.

Comment: do you have the properties file that has my.value set? something like my.value=true. spring searches the property in environment.

check whether your application.properties or any other properties you have explicitly wired have above property set